# MySQL: Indexes on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a reasonably big table (>10.000 rows) which is going to grow much bigger fast. On this table I run the following query:

```
SELECT *, MAX(a) FROM table GROUP BY b, c, d
```

Currently EXPLAIN tells me that there are no keys, no possible keys and it's "Using temporary; Using filesort". What would the best key be for such a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end what worked was a modification to the query as follows:

```
SELECT b, c, d, e, f, MAX(a) FROM table GROUP BY b, c, d
```

And creating an index on (b, c, d, e, f).

Thanks a lot for your help: the tips here were very useful.

Answer (score 4):

What about composite key `b+c+d+a`?

Btw, `SELECT *` makes no sense in case when you have `GROUP BY`

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance, but could you unpack your statement "Btw, SELECT * makes no sense in case when you have GROUP BY"?

Comment: @Adrien Hingert: every column in `SELECT` should be either used in `GROUP BY` or with aggregation function (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc). Otherwise it is "not possible" to say which values to select. All "mature" databases such as SQL Server, Oracle or Postgres follow this ANSI SQL requirement, but mysql doesn't (it has a special mode to turn it on though)

Answer (score 2):

A primary index on field b,c,d would be nice if applicable.
In that case you just do a

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
group by <insert PRIMARY KEY here>
```

If not put an index on b,c,d.
And maybe on a, depends on the performance.

If b,c,d are always used in unison, use a composite index on all three.

Very important! Always declare a primary key. Without it performance on InnoDB will suck.

To elaborate on @zerkms, you only need to put those columns in the group by clause that completely define the rows that you are selecting.
If you `select *` that may be OK, but than the max(a) is not needed and neither is the group by.
Also note that the `max(a)` may come from a different row than the rest of the fields.

The only use case that does make sense is:

```
select t1.*, count(*) as occurrence from t1 
inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.manytoone_id) 
group by t1.id
```

Where t1.id is the PK.

**I think you need to rethink that query.**
Ask a new question explaining what you want with the real code.
And make sure to ask `how to make the outcome`determinate`, so that all values shown are functionally dependent on the group by clause`.

Comment: Any reason for `b+c+d` index to be primary?

Comment: "Very important! Always declare a primary key. Without it performance on InnoDB will suck." --- yes, it is obvious, but **why do you insist on grouping by PK**?? What is the significant difference between groupping by PK and regular not-null key????

Comment: "If you select * that may be OK, but than the max(a) is not needed." --- it is not ok. It completely makes no sense with groupping

Comment: @zerkms, that depends, if you have the PK in the group by clause, all fields from that table will be functionally dependent on the group by and select * is not a problem. However in that case the `group by` is not needed. If you do a `select t1.* from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.id = t2.manytoone_id) group by t1.id` where id is the PK, then that makes perfect sense. I agree this does not.

Comment: lol. If you `group by` complete PK - then it is pointless, as long as each set will refer to exactly one row. If you `group by` part of PK - then `select *` will depend on a set of rows.

Comment: About your query sample - `t1.*` will contain `1..N` row per each `t1.id` and even they contain the same information - for DBMS they aren't. If all you need to do with `t2` is just to filter the data - move it to `WHERE` with subquery and remove `group by` at all.

Comment: @zerkms, it can make sense when you're joining. If not then it doesn't, see the updated answer.

Comment: it is ANSI SQL invalid query.

Comment: @zerkms, you cannot do a count(*) per id without a `group by`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3677/discussion-between-johan-and-zerkms)